# Libre Office Sign a PDF with PGP key

Tags: pdf, libreoffice, pgp, digital-signature

I'm currently facing an issue with the "Sign" feature of Libre Office. I can digital sign my ODT files without a problem. That means I can select my pgp key in the list of keys and sign the odt document.
[Picture: list of keys to choose from when signing a odt file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8ZYf.png)

But when I want to sign a pdf file (which is generated from the odt file above) the list of possible keys is empty.
[Picture: Empty list of pgp keys.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Z8P0.png)

Does anyone have an idea how I can fix this?

Comment: I suspect PDF's cannot be signed by PGP keys, but only by X509 certificates.

Comment: I also suspect this, but I can't find any information about this. All tutorials I find online explain how to signa PDF with a PGP key and after that they also explain  that signing a PDF is the same way. No hint or something that a PGP key is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

The [PDF standard](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/PDF32000_2008.pdf) (Section 12.8.3 - Signature Interoperability) only mentions X.509 certificates and therefore I suspect that PDF's cannot be signed by PGP keys, but only by X.509 certificates.

This is only my interpretation of the PDF 1.7 standard and I have not read the whole document, this is why I hesitated to post this as an answer. Indeed there may exist an extension to the standard that allows one to use PGP keys for signatures.

PS: This may also be of interest to you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k8FIDGmmYvs